# Record count and cksum on compressed file

Tags: bash, shell-script, compression, checksum

There is a file of 40 GB in gz format. I want to find the record count and `cksum` of this file in uncompressed format. One approach I have is:

1. Unzip the file using `gunzip`
2. Use `wc`, `cksum` commands on unzipped file
3. Zip the file again using `gzip`.

Problem with this approach is extracting and compressing the file will be taking lot of time. May be around 30-40 mins. Another approach may be using `zcat` to calculate record count and `cksum`

1. `zcat <file name> | wc -l`
2. `zcat <file name> | cksum`

This approach may take less time, but using `zcat` twice on same file. Is there a better approach? May be using one command to find both record count and `cksum`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tee` and bash's [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) this:

```
$ zcat foo.gz | tee >(md5sum >&2) | wc
6f869e2acc27a0330b10d9ffa6655e7b  -
  36568   45710 2743552
```

That decompresses the file once, passes the decompressed data to `tee` which passes it as an input file to `md5sum` which is told to print its output to standard error (and therefore isn't caught by `| wc`), and then we also pass the output to `wc`.

Comment: Or `{ zcat foo.gz 3>&- | tee >(md5sum >&3 3>&-) | wc 3>&-; } 3>&1` to send `md5sum`'s output to stdout as well like in the zsh approach.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas why? I mean why do something that complicated instead of just `{ zcat foo.gz | tee >(md5sum >&2) | wc; } 2>&1` if you want everything on stdout?

Comment: That would send the errors to stdout instead. It's not much more complicated and is more correct than hijacking a fd (2) that is intended for something else (errors).

Comment: Heh, I guess "complicated" is relative. I find that extremely complex and confusing. I can live with having one output sent to stderr and the other to stdout. Please feel free to include your approach in your answer though, if you explain it, I'd love to understand it better!

Comment: @terdon slightly changed your command to fit it into script. `$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
res=$( zcat test.txt.gz | tee >(cksum>.csum.tmp) | wc -l)
checksum=$(cat .csum.tmp|awk '{print $1}')
echo "check sum is: $checksum"
echo "Record count is: $res"
$ ./test.sh
check sum is: 3932802555
Record count is: 3
$` Anything else I should consider before using this approach?

Answer (score 6):

`moreutils` package on Debian (and elsewhere) contains a small treasure trove of general purpose utils.

One of them is `pee(1)`. It is just like `tee(1)` but does not write output to (several) files, but instead pipes it to (several) commands. It is extremely simple and intuitive to use; e.g.

```
$ zcat foo.gz | pee md5sum wc
0a22adb99b92b4c5ad6beba9694238a3  -
    403    2372   27766
```

Comment: Wow, `pee` is amazing

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't appear to have an issue with disk space, the simplest approach would be to decompress the file to a temporary file that you then run your two commands on.  Once you are done, you delete the temporary file.

```bash
gunzip -c file.gz >tmpname
wc -l tmpname
cksum tmpname
rm tmpname
```

You can replace `gunzip -c` with `gzip -d -c` or `zcat` if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

If using `zsh`:

```
{zcat file.gz} > >(wc -l) > >(cksum)
```

As stdout is redirected twice, zsh replaces it with a pipe to internal `tee`ing process that sends the output to both `wc -l` and `cksum`.

Note that `wc` and `cksum` are run concurrently and which one outputs their result first is not deterministic.

Comment: zsh is not available. bash is the only option I have

Comment: @Gopi Then you should tag it with [tag:bash] or at least _mention_ bash somewhere in the question.

Comment: @pipe Tagged with bash